# Recyclerview não exibe os dados

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-recyclerview

Estou com um problema em que a RecyclerView não renderiza na activity. As TextViews carregam normalmente.

No Emulador utilizo as Apis de level 24 ou 30 e dipositivos físicos.

Esta aparecendo desta forma, o Recycler fica logo abaixo da TextView 'Portal de clientes':

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Já tentei revisar com o debugger porém não acusa erro. Verifiquei o adapter na activity e esta recebendo e processando os dados normal. Raramente os dados são renderizados mas ainda sim são, mesmo com uma frequência minima de sucesso.

Seguem os códigos:

Obrigado desde já !

Adapter:

```
public class AdapterBrand extends RecyclerView.Adapter<HolderBrand> {

    private static final String TAG = "Adapter Brand";
    //private static final RecyclerView.RecycledViewPool sharedPool = new RecyclerView.RecycledViewPool();

    private final ArrayList<Brand> mArr;
    private final Context context;

    public AdapterBrand(Context context, ArrayList<Brand> mArr) {
        this.context = context;
        this.mArr = mArr;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public HolderBrand onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        return new HolderBrand(LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.item_brand_grid, parent, false));

    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull HolderBrand holder, int position) {
        
        final String brandImage;
        try {

            

                brandImage = mArr.get(position).getImagem();
                holder.onBind(brandImage, holder);

            

        } catch (Exception ex){
            Log.e(TAG, "onBindViewHolder: ", ex);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mArr == null ? 1 : mArr.size();
    }

}
```

Holder:

```
public class HolderBrand  extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    private static final String TAG = "Holder Brand";
    private final ImageButton imageButton;

    public HolderBrand(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        imageButton = itemView.findViewById(R.id.image_title_button_grid);

    }

    public void onBind(String brandImage, HolderBrand holder){

        Picasso.get()
                .load(brandImage)
                .fit()
                .into((ImageButton) holder.imageButton);
    }


}
```

Activity:

```
public class ListUsersActivity extends AppCompatActivity  {
    private static final String TAG =  "List Users Activity";

    private ListUsersActivity listUsersActivity;

    public ArrayList<Brand> arrayList;
    public ArrayAdapter<Brand> arrayAdapter;
    private RecyclerView brandList;


    @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_list_users);

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String text = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.Texto_extra);

        //Recebe o texto do campo email para as boas vindas no txtVwEmailFromActv1.
        TextView emailTxt1 = findViewById(R.id.txtVwEmailFromActv1);
        emailTxt1.setText("Bem vindo " + "\r\n" + text);

        brandList = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);

        try {
            listUsersActivity = this;

            setComponents();
            new apiAcess(this).getBrands();

        } catch (Exception ex){
            Log.e(TAG, "onCreate: ", ex);
        }



    }


    private void setComponents(){

        arrayList  = new ArrayList<>();
        arrayAdapter  = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, R.layout.item_brand_grid, arrayList);
        brandList.setAdapter(new AdapterBrand(this, arrayList));
        GridLayoutManager gridLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(this, 3);
        gridLayoutManager.setInitialPrefetchItemCount(3);
        Log.d(TAG, "InitialPrefetchItemCount iniciado");
        brandList.setLayoutManager(gridLayoutManager);
        //AdapterBrand.brandLayoutMg(brandList, gridLayoutManager);
    }
}
```

Layout Recycler:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtVwEmailFromActv1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="74dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
        android:text="@string/activity_2"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="#171616"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/presenter1"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/presenter1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:text="@string/presenterBrands"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="#171616"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:textStyle="bold|italic"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/recyclerView"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/txtVwEmailFromActv1"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints" />

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView

        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/presenter1"
        tools:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.GridLayoutManager"
        tools:listitem="@layout/item_brand_grid"
        tools:spanCount="3" />


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Layout item:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/cardView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="5dp">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">


        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/image_title_button_grid"
            android:layout_width="123dp"
            android:layout_height="96dp"
            android:layout_margin="8dp"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:contentDescription="@string/brandlogo"
            android:contextClickable="true"
            android:focusable="true"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.078"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.454"
            tools:srcCompat="@tools:sample/avatars[3]" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

apiAcess:

```
public class apiAcess {

    private static final String TAG = "apiAcess";

    private final ListUsersActivity lActivity;

    public apiAcess(ListUsersActivity lActivity) {
        this.lActivity = lActivity;
    }

    public void getBrands(){
        try {
            TaskManager.getINSTANCE().createTask(() -> {
                try {
                    final api getBrand = brandJson.createService(api.class);

                    String jsonFile = "http://" + BuildConfig.URL_BRANDS_JSON;

                    Call<ResponseBody> callApi = getBrand.getAllBrands(jsonFile);

                    callApi.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseBody>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(Call<ResponseBody> call, Response<ResponseBody> response) {
                            if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                                try {
                                    TaskManager.getINSTANCE().createTask(() -> {
                                        try {
                                            String responseBd = response.body().string();
                                            Portais n = new Gson().fromJson(responseBd, Portais.class);

                                            Log.d(TAG, "onResponse: Portais: " + n.getPortais());;
                                            //aqui é onde todos os valores do arquivo .json são recebidos em formato de array de objetos
                                            lActivity.runOnUiThread(() -> {
                                                lActivity.arrayList.addAll(n.getPortais());
                                                lActivity.arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                                            });


                                        } catch (Exception ex) {
                                            Log.e(TAG, "onResponse: ", ex);
                                        }
                                    });
                                } catch (Exception ex) {
                                    Log.e(TAG, "createTask: ", ex);
                                }

                            }

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(Call<ResponseBody> call, Throwable t) {
                            Log.e(TAG, "onFailure: ", t);
                        }
                    });

                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "TaskManager: ", ex);
                }


            });

        }catch (Exception ex){
            Log.e(TAG, "getBrands: ", ex);
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O erro em si era o método setComponents da Activity

foi substituído:

```
arrayAdapter  = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, R.layout.item_brand_grid, arrayList);
brandList.setAdapter(new AdapterBrand(this, arrayList));
```

por:

```
    arrayAdapter  = new AdapterBrand(this, arrayList);
    brandList.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
```

O adapter do tipo da model não estava sendo usado, pois estava sendo declarado outro vazio antes. Após alterar e instanciar somente em arrayAdapter, funcionou em dispositivos e no emulador.

Answer (score 0):

Opa, fala Filipe! Tudo bom?

Cara, olhando seu código... não consegui encontrar o momento que você popula a array do adapter.
Vejo que você manda uma lista vazia pra ele:

```
arrayList  = new ArrayList<>();
arrayAdapter  = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, R.layout.item_brand_grid, arrayList);
brandList.setAdapter(new AdapterBrand(this, arrayList));
```

Mas não encontrei em nenhuma parte o momento que você submete a nova lista de objetos `Brand` pro adapter.

Será que tem a ver com esta linha aqui que não atribui valor a nenhuma variável?

```
   new apiAcess(this).getBrands();
```

Tente criar uma função pra submeter a nova lista pro adapter e logo em seguida executar um `notifyDatasetChanged()` para renderizar novamente os itens da sua recyclerView.

Por exemplo (dentro do seu adapter):

```
public void submitList(List<Brand> brandList) {
  mArr = brandList;
  notifyDatasetChanged();
}
```

Mas te aconselho fortemente a pesquisar sobre [**RecyclerView**](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/recyclerview?hl=pt-br) e [**DiffUtils**](https://iammert.medium.com/using-diffutil-in-android-recyclerview-bdca8e4fbb00) para compreender um pouco melhor.

Espero ter ajudado, abraços!

### EDIT:

Agora com o arquivo apiAccess ficou melhor de entender.
Cara, não aconselho você passar referência de activity pra sua camada de API.
Dê uma olhada [**neste link**](https://medium.com/@amtechnovation/android-architecture-component-mvvm-part-1-a2e7cff07a76), ele ensina a popular uma recycler view utilizando boas práticas.

Maaas, resolvendo seu problema de forma direta, você está populando a variável referente à activity e não ao adapter. O que deve ser modificado é o `mArr` que está dentro do adapter.

```
lActivity.arrayList.addAll(n.getPortais());
lActivity.arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Então, seguindo sua lógica de implementação, você teria que fazer 2 funções na activity:

- Uma função para inicializar o adapter e recyclerview (basicamente o setcomponents);
- E outra função para enviar a lista que você recebeu da api. Basicamente um `lActivity.submitList(n.getPortais())`. Essa é a função que estará na Activity e que fará a ponte pro adapter.

  Como é um processo assíncrono, deve existir essa função (como se fosse uma função de callback) para realizar a alteração na activity. Caso contrário, você não vai conseguir prever em que momento a lista chega da request pra poder popular seu adapter ;)